# Setting a stretching background image with position top

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website that has a .gif background, but the image is not the same size as my website page, so I need to stretch it. 
However, I have a 140px header, which hides a big part of my background image, so I put this code in CSS:

```
body{
  text-align:center;
  background:url('file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Bulgaria Animated Flag.gif');
  background-position:center 140px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;    
}
```

ALL CSS:

```css
html,body {
 margin:0px auto;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 min-width:1320px;
 text-align:center;
}

body{
 text-align:center;
 background:url('file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Bulgaria Animated Flag.gif');
 background-position:center 140px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 background-size:cover);
 
}
header{
 height:140px;
 width:100%;
 z-index:999;
 position:fixed;
 margin-top:-16px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:darkred;
 opacity:0.95;
}
#banner{
 width:1320px;
 height:500px;
 position:fixed;
 top:140px;
 background-color:rgba(256, 33, 18,0.8);
 text-align:center;
 margin:0px auto 0px auto;
 float:none;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}
#content{
 width:1320px;
 position:relative;
 top:626px;
 background:#ebebeb;
 height:1500px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 z-index:10;
}


/*CSS Dropdown Menu*/


ul{
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 padding:0px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
ul a{
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul li{
 float:left;
 width:130px;
 height:38px;
 background-color:red;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height:38px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:2px;
}
ul li a:hover{
 background-color:orangered;
}
ul li a{
 display:block;
 color:black;
}
ul li ul li{
 display:none;
 margin:0px;
}
ul li:hover ul li{
 display:block;
}

/*Slider*/

#slider{
 width:720px;
 height:480px;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 left:0;
 top:10px;
 bottom:0;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.info{
 width:720px;
 height:50px;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 background:black;
 opacity:0.8;
 z-index:1;
 bottom:65px;
 text-align:left;
}
.info h2{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:white;
 padding:5px 0 0 20px;
}
.info p{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:lighter;
 color:white;
 padding:30 0 0 20px;
 line-height:1px;
 
}
img{
 z-index:0;
}
#next{
 width:40px;
 height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 top:220px;
 right:10px;
 background-color:black;
 opacity:0.5;
 color:white;
 z-index:2;
 font-size:45px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#prev{
 width:40px;
 height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 top:220px;
 left:10px;
 background-color:black;
 opacity:0.5;
 color:white;
 z-index:2;
 font-size:45px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#pager{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:;
 background::;
 color:;
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index:3;
}
#pager a{
 width:10px;
 height:10px;
 display:inline-block;
 border:1px solid #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <header>
   <h1>HEADER</h1>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Option1</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option1.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option1.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option1.4</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option2.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option2.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option2.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option2.4</a></li>
     </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option3</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option3.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option3.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option3.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option3.4</a></li>
     </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option4</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option4.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option4.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option4.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option4.4</a></li>
     </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option5</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option5.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option5.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option5.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option5.4</a></li>
     </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option6</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option6.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option6.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option6.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option6.4</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </header>
  
  <div id="banner" style="margin:0px auto">
   
   <div id="slider">
   
    <div id="pager"></div>
    <div id="next">&gt;</div>
    <div id="prev">&lt;</div>
 
    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Albena_Bulgaria-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2>
     <p>Insert more text here</p>
     </div>   
    </div>
    
    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Rila_Monastery_Bulgaria-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2> 
     <p>Insert more text here</p>    
     </div>   
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Balchik_Bulgaria-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2> 
     <p>Insert more text here</p>    
     </div>    
        
    </div>

    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Belogradchik_Fortress_Bulgaria-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2> 
     <p>Insert more text here</p>    
     </div>    
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Burgas_coast_Bulgaria-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2> 
     <p>Insert more text here</p>    
     </div>    
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Downtown_Sofia_Boby_Dimitrov_1-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2> 
     <p>Insert more text here</p>    
     </div>    
        
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content">
   <p>Content</p>
  </div>
 </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Now the image is correctly displayed 140px under the top of the page. However, the image stretches 100% of *its own height*, not the height of the webpage, which means a big bottom part of it is not displayed. Many people have suggested putting a div, but this is not a solution for me, as my version of Expression Web has a bug, which messes up the webpage layout if you add a new div before already existing ones. I can always set height in px or %, but I am trying to achieve compatibility for all browsers.

Excuse me for incorrect formatting - this is my first question in the StackOverflow community.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest you to add HTML too (and probably create a jsFiddle/SO code snippet) to illustrate the issue and make it reproducible. Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will consider them.

Comment: Provide jsfiddle. Until then, you have my downvote.

Comment: @K.Daniek All the necessary code is already available in the question, so I really can't see the purpose of your down vote. Second, jsfiddle is **not** the recommended way to show a snippet, SO's own **Stack snippet** is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, here used CSS `calc()` for its height, `background-size: auto calc(100% - 140px);`

*Side note, as Daniel himself commented, and I missed in his code sample, there need to be space pre/post the operator in `calc()`.*

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: url('http://lorempizza.com/600/400/2');
  background-position: center 140px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: auto calc(100% - 140px);
}
```

If you need it to stretch full width, change the `auto` to `100%` on `background-size`

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: url('http://lorempizza.com/600/400/2');
  background-position: center 140px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
}
```

---

Based on your question edit, where you added more code, here is an update of it, with a stretched, positioned background image

By using `background-attachment: fixed;` it size with regard to the viewport, using `scroll` with regard to the element, in this case the `body`

```css
html,body {
 margin:0px auto;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 min-width:1320px;
 text-align:center;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: url('http://lorempizza.com/600/400/2');
  background-position: center 140px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% calc(100% - 140px);
}
header{
 height:140px;
 width:100%;
 z-index:999;
 position:fixed;
 margin-top:-16px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:darkred;
 opacity:0.95;
}
#banner{
 width:1320px;
 height:500px;
 position:fixed;
 top:140px;
 background-color:rgba(256, 33, 18, 0.5);    /* temp. increased transparency some so image shows better */
 text-align:center;
 margin:0px auto 0px auto;
 float:none;
 left:0;
 right:0;
}
#content{
 width:1320px;
 position:relative;
 top:626px;
 background:#ebebeb;
 height:1500px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 z-index:10;
}


/*CSS Dropdown Menu*/


ul{
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 padding:0px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
ul a{
 text-decoration:none;
}
ul li{
 float:left;
 width:130px;
 height:38px;
 background-color:red;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height:38px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:2px;
}
ul li a:hover{
 background-color:orangered;
}
ul li a{
 display:block;
 color:black;
}
ul li ul li{
 display:none;
 margin:0px;
}
ul li:hover ul li{
 display:block;
}

/*Slider*/

#slider{
 width:720px;
 height:480px;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 left:0;
 top:10px;
 bottom:0;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.info{
 width:720px;
 height:50px;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 background:black;
 opacity:0.8;
 z-index:1;
 bottom:65px;
 text-align:left;
}
.info h2{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:white;
 padding:5px 0 0 20px;
}
.info p{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight:lighter;
 color:white;
 padding:30 0 0 20px;
 line-height:1px;
 
}
img{
 z-index:0;
}
#next{
 width:40px;
 height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 top:220px;
 right:10px;
 background-color:black;
 opacity:0.5;
 color:white;
 z-index:2;
 font-size:45px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#prev{
 width:40px;
 height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 top:220px;
 left:10px;
 background-color:black;
 opacity:0.5;
 color:white;
 z-index:2;
 font-size:45px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#pager{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:;
 background::;
 color:;
 cursor:pointer;
 z-index:3;
}
#pager a{
 width:10px;
 height:10px;
 display:inline-block;
 border:1px solid #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <header>
   <h1>HEADER</h1>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Option1</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option1.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option1.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option1.4</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option2.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option2.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option2.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option2.4</a></li>
     </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option3</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option3.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option3.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option3.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option3.4</a></li>
     </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option4</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option4.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option4.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option4.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option4.4</a></li>
     </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option5</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option5.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option5.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option5.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option5.4</a></li>
     </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Option6</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Option6.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option6.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option6.3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Option6.4</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </header>
  
  <div id="banner" style="margin:0px auto">
   
   <div id="slider">
   
    <div id="pager"></div>
    <div id="next">&gt;</div>
    <div id="prev">&lt;</div>
 
    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Albena_Bulgaria-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2>
     <p>Insert more text here</p>
     </div>   
    </div>
    
    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Rila_Monastery_Bulgaria-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2> 
     <p>Insert more text here</p>    
     </div>   
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Balchik_Bulgaria-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2> 
     <p>Insert more text here</p>    
     </div>    
        
    </div>

    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Belogradchik_Fortress_Bulgaria-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2> 
     <p>Insert more text here</p>    
     </div>    
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Burgas_coast_Bulgaria-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2> 
     <p>Insert more text here</p>    
     </div>    
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="items">
    
     <img alt="Error" src="images/Downtown_Sofia_Boby_Dimitrov_1-720x480.jpg"/>
     <div class="info">
     <h2>Insert text here</h2> 
     <p>Insert more text here</p>    
     </div>    
        
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content">
   <p>Content</p>
  </div>
 </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What a smart answer! Tried it immediatly...but the image stays in it's default size. Tried changing you code, but still doesn't work. :-(

Comment: @DanielHalachev Well since this works based on how I understood your question, I'll need to see more of your code

Comment: Seems I will have to experiment on my own.

Comment: I found why it is not working - I must ALWAYS PUT SPACE BETWEEN "+" and "-"!

Comment: @DanielHalachev Well, yes, I missed that in your code, sorry, will post a note into my answer covering that as well, thanks.

Comment: I also thank you. I learned a brand new function. Also, I do apologise for any behaviour that might have insulted you during our conversation with Daniek. Best regards,

Comment: @DanielHalachev Was not offened :) ... you were spot on, to have focus on the solution